# pl/sql procedure to create view as select max, min from all columns

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a pl/sql procedure to create views containing max and min values of each column of each table of each schema in my DB. 
in order to compare the data between old rdb DB and new Oracle DB.
does any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a little bit of dynamic SQL, selecting info from `USER_TABLES` and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema and its `DEPT` and `SALGRADE` tables. You'd remove (or modify) the `WHERE` clause from `CUR_T` cursor loop.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(2000);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_t in (select table_name
  5                  from user_tables
  6                  where table_name in ('DEPT', 'SALGRADE')
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9
 10      l_str := 'create or replace view v_'  || cur_t.table_name  ||' as select ';
 11
 12      for cur_c in (select column_name
 13                    from user_tab_columns
 14                    where table_name = cur_t.table_name
 15                   )
 16      loop
 17        l_str := l_str ||
 18        ' min('  || cur_c.column_name ||') ' || cur_c.column_name ||'_min, ' ||
 19        ' max('  || cur_c.column_name ||') ' || cur_c.column_name ||'_max, ';
 20      end loop;
 21
 22      l_str := rtrim(l_str, ', ') || ' from ' || cur_t.table_name;
 23
 24      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 25      execute immediate(l_str);
 26    end loop;
 27  end;
 28  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select * from v_dept;

DEPTNO_MIN DEPTNO_MAX DNAME_MIN      DNAME_MAX      LOC_MIN       LOC_MAX
---------- ---------- -------------- -------------- ------------- -------------
        10         40 ACCOUNTING     SALES          BOSTON        NEW YORK

SQL> select * from v_salgrade;

 GRADE_MIN  GRADE_MAX  LOSAL_MIN  LOSAL_MAX  HISAL_MIN  HISAL_MAX
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5        700       3001       1200       9999

SQL>
```